# How do correspondence players keep track of ideas during games?

Tags: correspondence-chess, planning

I've taken up correspondence chess again, and planning has always been one of my biggest weaknesses. It's still something with which I struggle. Besides analyzing specific variations, how do correspondence players keep track of the plans they want to execute, or prevent their opponent from carrying out, during a game?

For example, in a recent game, I knew I needed to not let my opponent put his rook on the 7th rank, as he would likely win another pawn, which I let happen a few moves later.

Comment: I'm not sure about the question. That depends your position? Do you have an example?

Comment: Correspondence players are allowed to make notes during the game.

Comment: No, I mean in general. As I mentioned, I have trouble with making plans, so it's difficult to give an example.

Comment: @bof I'm aware of that. Basically l'm wanting to know what types of notes, or see some concrete examples, other than just a line of analysis.

Comment: So the question isn't really about *correspondence* chess: it's just about chess.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco no, it's about correspondence chess. In OTB, my thoughts are going to be fresh in my mind over a period of a few moves, as opposed to correspondence chess, where those few moves make take place over several days or weeks.

Comment: @HerbWolfe Well, then the question isn't about correspondence chess still, it is about how to take notes about things (which has little to do with chess in general).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I write a short description in my notebook for each move I make, unless it is a trivial move (e.g. a forced recapture, an opening move I know already or an endgame that I know already).

I try to imitate the style used in *Logical Chess* by Irving Chernev.

Answer (score 4):

Although it's been many years since I participated,  I used to play postal chess by snail mail.  For each game I would write down and keep analysis of significant lines each time I moved so I didn't forget them in the interval. I would also write notes concerning what ideas I had in general for the position.  I also tried to keep the number of games to a manageable amount to avoid confusion, generally 6 to 12 games at a time. I always had good results with this method.